# Get Link Click Count ( 1 Click per User)

Tags: javascript, php

I am building a social bookmarking site. Even non-logged users can click links and I count it.

I make a popular links list according to link count.

Even though non-logged users click SAME LINK many times withing a DAY, I need to consider it as a ONE CLICK. **How to do it?** I can do it using IP address. But it waste lots of server resources I think.

(If it is a logged user I handled this maintaining a table, that table has all the links and who is clicks).

Comment: Please can you tell me that why this post down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP -> Use a SESSION or COOKIE

JS -> COOKIE

If you aren't going to store the information in some sort of database, then ultimately the user will be able to repeat the process since you are relying on the browser to regulate, which the user can control (clear cache, cookies, etc.)

That's the only thing I can contribute.

Comment: If I use a session there is a another problem. There will be a thousands of sessions. It is a big load for server. Cookie? Hmm It is not bad. But user can easily open a private mode in browser again and again, and click again and again.

Comment: @Sasa1234 Are you concerned about server storage? I'm unsure why you think it would be taxing on the server?

Comment: @trickyzter Server storage is not a problem for me, but server functions matters me,. Because of I am in a shared hosting, I need to minimize as possible PHP functions as well as mysql requests.

Comment: @Sasa1234 Also note that private browsing will cause problems with server stored sessions, as the server utilises browser cookies to store the unique identifier.

Comment: @trickyzter Thanks, Do you have any idea how YouTube count video views? I think  same type of thing I want to do...

Comment: @Sasa1234 I assume YouTube has an algorithm for determining unique views, potentially reviewing the remote ip address. For performance you could use the database to manage sessions rather than the file system. http://www.hackingwithphp.com/10/3/7/files-vs-databases